# What was the mortality rate of the Black Death?

Tags: italy, black-death

There are primary sources indicating high mortality in Italy. But that's it. The 1m+ death estimates seem to all originate from a single person writing in the 19th century (Gasquet). Gasquet has been criticized for poor methodology. The high death rate among nobles could be due to inbreeding and may not correlate with the overall population.

Are there are any  primary sources indicating that the black death had a 1m+ death toll ?

Comment: What have you found out yourself? On Wikipedia, for example?

Comment: What do you call *primary sources* if they "*all originate from a single person writing in the 19th century (Gasquet)*" ? That would make them a **secondary** source in my dictionnary. Anyway, links to some of those sources would be helpful, and also precision about the period you refer to (I suspect mid-14th century but there has been several Plague epimedics in Italy during History...)

Comment: There's no reason to expect primary sources to be accurate on this regard. You're better off asking for modern scientific estimates if you're trying to discern the real mortality rate. I don't know how you managed to think "inbreeding" has anything to do with it, though.